# Programmable CPU cache?

Tags: caching, cpu

Is it possible to use  CPU's cache the same way as main memory? e.g. saving variables there?

CPUs in my lab have plenty of L3 cache (Xeon E5), nvidia's GPU has managable shared-memory/cache, and there are quite some tricks for performance-ehnancement enabled by such programmable cache,  is there a way to do the same with CPU's huge amount of cache?

Comment: The CPU already does this for you, transparently - what are you hoping to achieve ?

Comment: Using them as very fast storage

Comment: This already happens, transparently - that's the whole point of a cache - what do you think that you can do better ?

Comment: If the cache become programmable, then it is possible to re-arrange your algorithm completely to achieve some macro-level optimsation, just like we did with shared-memory in GPUs.

Comment: The shared memory on GPUs et al is just explicitly managed cache - it's explicitly managed to save silicon - on a general purpose CPU this is all handled automatically for you by logic which is missing on a GPU. The way to improve performance is to make your algorithm more cache-friendly, not try to micro-manage the cache (which you can't even do in any meaningful way on most CPUs in any case).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a processor with "scratchpad memory", which is commonly used by GPUs/vector processors in lieu of more sophisticated caching protocols. This is the "programmable cache" you referred to on the Nvidia GPU.

To my knowledge no x86 CPUs have this, however it's quite common to see ARM processors with a "core-coupled" low-latency SRAM block that may be used as scratchpad RAM.

Answer (score 2):

In some architectures like MIPS, it is possible to use privileged instruction to 'lock' cachelines. So that the cache can be read/write and won't be flushed out during LRU. It is similar to scratchpad ram in the processors.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that a decent compiler will be able to make much more efficient use of the cache than you could possibly do yourself without a lot of effort.

Comment: I am sure nowadays compilers can be very efficient at micro-level optimisation, but I learnt some cache-algorithms, most of which are quite simple, I suspect by enabling programmable cache just like nvidia's shared local memory, alot of more macro-level optimization can be applied.